# How to solve this TypeError in LinkController#callback rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi all this is the code that i use

```
user = client.profile(:fields => %w(positions))
    puts "User client :"+user.positions[0]
```

when i run the code i get the below error.

```
TypeError in LinkController#callback
can't convert LinkedIn::Position::Resource into Stringcan't convert LinkedIn::Position::Resource into String
```

please do help me to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to convert it in string?

```
puts "User client :"+user.positions[0].to_s
```

Or better :

```
puts "User client :#{user.positions[0]}"
```